# ¿Cómo puedo asignar la ruta del archivo que abre una Access DB a una celda en Excel?

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, vba, ms-access, oledb

tengo una conexión conexión desde Excel con Ms Access definida en la siguiente línea:

```
Public Const con1 As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\co1140890727\Desktop\Proyecto\I&A-DataBase.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database;"
```

Me gustaría poder asignar el DataSource a una celda en mi hoja de cálculo que contenga la ruta en texto. Algo como esto:

```
DBPath = Range("A1").Value
Public Const con1 As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DBPath
```

Comment: ¿Y qué problema tienes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé si estoy 100% en lo cierto pero una constante no puede tener elementos variables, cómo en tu caso es el contenido de la celda. Has probado así?:

```
DBPath = Range("A1").Value
Public con1 As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DBPath
```

Otra manera que a lo mejor te interesa más:

```
Public Const DBPath As String = "$AB$1"
```

Y luego en tú sub:

```
Sub conexion ()

   Dim con1 As String
   
   con1 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Range(DBPath).value

End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. La segunda opción se acerca a lo que quiero hacer pero obtengo el siguiente error:       -2147467259:No se pudo encontrar el archivo 'C:\Users\co1140890727\Documents\$B$17'.   No sé si es por como tengo definida la ruta en la celda. Estoy usando la Celda B17 que contiene la ruta de la siguiente manera: "C:\Users\co1140890727\Desktop\Proyecto\I&A-DataBase.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database;"

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta. Añade Range(DBPath).Value para que "saque" el valor de la celda y no la celda en si. A ver si te funciona.

Comment: Funciona! Muchas gracias@dogwall!!